# Can't display data from mySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm running a small rPi server (Apache2, php5 installed), and I was doing some research on how to display data onto a webpage from a SQL data base. So, thorough phpMyAdmin, I created a small database called "Test" using phpMyAdmin, and it has two columns (Name, Age), and three rows. I followed an tutorial on how to connect to it, and created these two files. However, I keep getting my "die" message of "Error connecting to database". Any help on what I might have done wrong would be appreciated! Feel free to request any additional details.

connect.php

```
$dbcon  = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME); //Connect 

if(!$dbcon) {
die('Error connecting to database');
}

echo 'You have Connected Successfully';
?>
```

chonline.php

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

$test = $dbcon;
echo $test;
?>
```

index.html

```
<html><body><h1>Raspberry Pi Test Page!</h1>
<p>If you see this message,rPi server is up and running.</p>
<p>Server Public IP: 67.164.104.19.</p>
</body>

<a href = "test.php">TableTest</a>
<a href = "chonline.php">Connection Successful?</a>
</html>
```

Comment: You say you created a **database** with two columns and three rows. Am I to understand that you meant you created a **table**?

Comment: have you set `DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME` values ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `mysqli_connect_error()` - also, shouldn't you use `localhost` as database host, I'm assuming the MySQL server is running on the rPi?

Comment: In the [manual page](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) you can find several usage examples on how to read the error message.

Comment: Maybe you haven't set the privilege to connect from your server to that IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
define('DB_HOST', '67.164.104.19');
```

to

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

See if that gets you anywhere.